# Repositório não eliminado completamente, SVN status dá-me pontos de exclamação

Tags: svn

Estamos usando SVN como *versioning system* para um website que estamos construindo para a escola mas tenho alguns problemas.

Uma minha colega tinha criado uma pasta que depois eu tentei eliminar, mas parece que não foi eliminada. E quando faço `svn status`, aparece-me isto:

```
!       sengineering
!       sengineering/images
!M      sengineering/images/The_C_Programming_Language_2_ed.png
!M      sengineering/images/W3C®_Icon.svg.png
!M      sengineering/images/cs_go_scene.jpg
!M      sengineering/images/history.png
!M      sengineering/images/lambda.png
!M      sengineering/images/oop.png
!       sengineering/languages
!       sengineering/languages/languages.html
!       sengineering/languages/languages_evolution.html
!       sengineering/languages/most_important_pl.html
!       sengineering/languages/programming_language.html
!       sengineering/multitask.html
!       sengineering/sengineering.html
```

`sengineering` foi a pasta que tentei eliminar.

Eu vi que o ponto de exclamação é relacionado ao fato que eu não tenho essa pasta, mas como faço eu a fazer um `checkout` de novo a especifica pasta, ou como faço eu a elimina-la completamente?

Comment: O `svn status` está dizendo que a pasta existe no repositório mas não existe na sua máquina, pois você a excluiu da sua área de trabalho. Além de deletar a pasta localmente, você precisa também *commitar* esta remoção.

Comment: Parece que você tem exclusões e adições pendentes de commit. Você tem outras alterações locais que pretende commitar além desta deleção?

Comment: Pergunto sobre sua intenção: deseja commitar mais coisas além de uma exclusão? Se não, experimente baixar todo o repositório em outra pasta e fazer a exclusão por URL, a qual commita as alterações imediatamente. Em seguida (se deu tudo certo) você refaz a sua pasta de trabalho original (exclui e baixa tudo de novo) e bola pra frente.

Comment: O `revert` é para você abrir mão das alterações locais; ou seja, você não quer nunca mais mandar isso pro servidor. Não tem relação com alterar irreversivelmente o repositório no servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Para deletar uma pasta ou diretório do **SVN** (**Subversion**) *commitando* imediatamente esta exclusão, use o comando `svn delete` passando a URL da pasta no repositório em vez de passar o caminho local da pasta. Assim:

```
svn delete -m "comentário..." svn://servidor/repo/pasta/pasta_a_deletar
```

Sendo que o último parâmetro é a URL, que pode ter algumas variações: `file:///...` ou `http://dominio...`. Use a URL que você está acostumado a usar em suas outras operações.

Comment: Isso, elimina local e commita, numa única operação.

Comment: O `-m` é para indicar a mensagem, o comentário que você é obrigado a fazer quando exclui algo. O que determina que a exclusão é imediata no repositório é o fato de você indicar a URL da pasta no repositório em vez de indicar o caminho local da pasta.